# ¿Por qué me aparece este aviso: Setting a random_state has no effect since shuffle is False?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Cuando utilizo los clasificadores que os muestro a continuación, me aparece el numero de aciertos pero sin embargo, me aparece un aviso, no entiendo el aviso ni que parámetro debo modificar ¿Alguien me puede orientar?

Ademas, he modificado el `radmon_state` a `None` y tampoco se me soluciona

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=1000)
names = [
         "SVM",
         "Decision Tree",
         "GaussianNB",
         "RandomForestClassifier",
         "KNeighborsClassifier(3)"

]
classifiers = [
  SVC(probability=True),
  DecisionTreeClassifier(),
  GaussianNB(),
  RandomForestClassifier(),
  KNeighborsClassifier(13)

]


cv = sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, random_state=123)#semilla por donde tiene que empezar a barajar
for name, clf in zip(names, classifiers):
  results = np.round(cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=cv),2)#le pasamos cv para que lo resuelva
  print(f'{name:22s} media aciertos: {results.mean():.2} resultados: {results}')
```

la salida es:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py:296: FutureWarning: Setting a random_state has no effect since shuffle is False. This will raise an error in 0.24. You should leave random_state to its default (None), or set shuffle=True FutureWarning
```

Answer (score 2):

Bien, en tu

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=1000)
names = [
         "SVM",
         "Decision Tree",
         "GaussianNB",
         "RandomForestClassifier",
         "KNeighborsClassifier(3)"

]
```

te hace falta el "shuffle" así `shuffle=True`.

Sólo haría falta agregarlo dentro de tu modelo de selección para entrenamiento y prueba.

`X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=1000, shuffle=True)`

En la versión(Version 0.22.2.post) de scikit learn, ellos acomodaron algunos errroes, entre ellos, el siguiente: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que te dice que si es `shuffle=false`, arrojará un error. En tu caso, no lo habías colocado, si lo colocas, no debería arrojarte un error.

Te dejo la página, por si te sirve para alguna otra búsqueda: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new/v0.22.html

Espero haberte ayudado en algo.

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por tu aportación. Sin embargo, al mdificarlo me sigue apareciendo el "error"

FutureWarning: Setting a random_state has no effect since shuffle is False. This will raise an error in 0.24. You should leave random_state to its default (None), or set shuffle=True.
  FutureWarning

Comment: Disminuye el valor del random state a 1. O sea, igualalo a 1. Y luego prueba si ahora te funciona.

Comment: Acabo de cambiarlo:
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=1,shuffle=True)
 y me sigue apareciendo ese aviso, he buscado por todos lados y no he encontrado la forma de solucionarlo

Comment: ¿Lo intentaste con ambos random_state? Recuerda que usas dos.

Comment: Coloca el shuffle=True en el de abajo, cambia el n_splits = 5 y no a 10. Y también trata de cambiar el random_state, aunque eso no importa mucho, puedes colocar el numero que sea en el random_state y el resultado siempre será el mismo.

Comment: no me había dado cuenta, pensé q me habías dicho solo en el primero. Se me ha solucionado. MUCHÍSIMAS GRACIAS

Comment: Una pregunta que me ha dejado intrigada. ¿por qué se deberia poner eso? a que hace referencia o porque evita que se produzca ese aviso?

Comment: Puedes cliquear como "solucionada" tu pregunta en la parte de abajo de las flechitas, y así otros podrán ver la solución. Te explico ahora tu duda. El shuffle, en el entrenamiento, creo que no debería ser usado, trata ahora de probar quitandolo de ahí(arriba) y dejándolo abajo. Dado que el shuffle lo que hace es que reorganizar los datos y hará que el resultado sea mejor porque hará que se entrene mejor.

Comment: Te dejaré aquí, una documentación que te hará entender mejor el trabajo de tu data: https://medium.com/@julie.yin/understanding-the-data-splitting-functions-in-scikit-learn-9ae4046fbd26 espero que te sirva de ayuda, e incluso esto: https://forums.fast.ai/t/shuffle-true-or-false/1438